# How to check if all drivers are up-to-date

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Is there a way to check if all installed drivers are the correct/best ones and if they are up-to-date? Background of my question: I have installed Windows 7 on a Notebook (2006). The manufacturer of that Notebook says that Windows 7 is not supported. Nevertheless, it is running :-) Unfortunately, it is not really stable: once a day I get a blue screen. I guess that I do not have the best fitting drivers and in the device manager of Windows there are two entries "Basic device" with a warning mark beside them... so can I do a "select all and check for driver updates" somehow?

Comment: As a general rule, most drivers written for Vista will run in 7. Not all, but most - so, as long as they support Vista... I have no idea how you could check for updates, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try running a driver tool like [driver identifier](http://www.driveridentifier.com/), will tell you if some driver has an update ...

Answer (score 1):

I have had some success with [SlimDrivers](http://majorgeeks.com/SlimDrivers_d6737.html) - it's pretty widely available at reputable sites and gets reasonable reviews. It will try and install toolbars and other rubbish but you can opt out of these during the install. I normally install this as required, run it a few times and then uninstall when finished. It does backup any changes so don't uninstall until you have verified everything working ok.

Answer (score 0):

There is many general/all-in-one tools that try to find and install driver updates, personally I do not recommend these. However if manufacturer has it's own tool it may (or may not) properly install drivers.

At least tools provided by IBM & Lenovo works reasonably well, in most cases all drivers updated. HP also has own update tool but my experience is that in most case it will not update or install anything. Others also provide their own tools but I think that I dont have enough experience with others to say if those are good or not.

Also there is update tools provided by component/ic/expansion card manufacturers including intel and nvidia.